# Finding difference between two dates , excluding non work days

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need the result amount of days in between two dates , excluding non workdays.

[image]

Some definitions

```
Sales[date1]
Sales[date2]

DeterminesWeekDay = WEEKDAY(Payment[Deposit Date],3) 


Weekend -Weekday = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    Sales[DeterminesWeekDay] = 0, "Weekday",
    Sales[DeterminesWeekDay] = 1, "Weekday",
    Sales[DeterminesWeekDay] = 2, "Weekday",
    Sales[DeterminesWeekDay] = 3, "Weekday",
    Sales[DeterminesWeekDay] = 4, "Weekday",
    Sales[DeterminesWeekDay] = 5, "Weekend",
    Sales[DeterminesWeekDay] = 6, "Weekend",
    BLANK()
)
```

My dax function I am stuck on , making a new measure or column.

```
WorkDaysOnly = 
CALCULATE(DATEDIFF(MIN(Sales[date1]),MIN(Sales[date2]),DAY),
        FILTER(Sales, Sales[Weekend -Weekday] = "Weekday") )
```

heres where I dont know how I would select the difference between my two dates, its still counting the weekends.

Example , date1 = 6/7/2019  and date2 =6/10/2019 , what I am expecting is one day not 3.  Would it be best to duplicate my date cols and remove all weekend dates, how ?

Comment: can you post a picture of your data model?

Comment: I have updated with the data .

Comment: @RADO How would I copy date1 column and add my filter to it (FILTER(Sales, Sales[Weekend -Weekday] = "Weekday") ) to have a date1 column with no weekends ?

Comment: do you have a calender table/dimension?
With a 1 or 0 for IsWeekDay column its a simple sum to the table, something along the lines of CALCUATE(SUM(calendartable[IsWeekDay]), FILTER(Calender[Date], Date  >= Sales[date1] && Date <= Sales[date1] )

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create following measure

```
No of working days = CALCULATE(SUM('calendar'[isWroking]),DATESBETWEEN('calendar'[Date],Sales[Date 1],Sales[Date 2]))


   isWroking = IF(WEEKDAY('calendar'[Date],2)<=5,1,0)
```

**Note isWorking should be created in calendar table